# play20 app (v. 2.0.2) deployment on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Trying to get a play 2.0.2 application going on heroku and it seems it is not yet supported.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Error:

```
          http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



   :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
   unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found
   Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
     (see /tmp/build_7sg3kay36u6a/project/boot/update.log for complete log)
   Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.11.3
 !     Failed to build app with SBT 0.11.0
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Scala app
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Are you upgrading a 2.0.1 app or is this app new?

Comment: Did you properly update your `project/build.properties` by setting `sbt.version=0.11.3` ?

Answer (score 3):

This was happening because of old cache (my app had been deployed on heroku before, hence the old cache)

From the root of your play application, do

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL='https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala#cleancache'
```

then push your app again

This will drop all cached artifacts and the sbt jar and re-download up to date fresh ones.

Just remember to do heroku config:remove BUILDPACK_URL afterwards or each time you push the cache will be dropped and builds will take a while.

Kudos to scott @ play googlegroups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/yUDfW2UtBjs

Answer (score 1):

This could be unrelated, but I had some conflicting plugin in `myhomedir/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` that messed up my Play 2.0.2 build. Removing that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error on my Mac and it was because MacPorts did not install the correct version of SBT (sudo port install sbt gave me 0.11.2 not 0.11.3) - yes I updated my port tree.  So I sudo port uninstalled sbt and used brew install sbt.  This (Homebrew) installed 0.11.3 and the problem disappeared.  I would suggest checking the sbt version on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this on play 2.0.4 (I know, this question is for play 2.0.2, but it's first on google):
change the sbt version to 0.11.3:
Change sbt version in project/build.properties to 0.11.3